# Cancel [cancel]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

On the few Questions I've looked at, [cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cancel) is used where, somewhere in the content, the Asker wants to *cancel* something. This happens on various unrelated things like cancelling...

- an action in some UI
- a command in some terminal
- a task (in thread terminology)
- something related to [file-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-io)

Is a tag like this worth keeping?

Answer (score 2):

From the look of things, this was a tag that mostly arose from folks trying to type titles into the tags field.

[image: burned]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it isn't worth keeping.

However, there are no questions tagged with only [cancel], so the tag is not preventing other more relevant tags from being placed on questions. I don't see how the tag is harming anything, and there are a lot of other actively harmful things going on that should be prioritized over burninating a merely useless tag.

Comment: Interesting point of view.  You could probably apply it to almost all of the current tag burnination requests and avoid a whole lot of unnecessary effort.

Comment: So, only sisyphean tasks should be started, like burninating a tag having more than 1000 questions, gaining 3+ per day? (This is not a comment on the validity of killing the tag, nor on the usefulness. There's much space between "not worth keeping" and "worth killing".)

Comment: @Deduplicator There are no questions tagged with _only_ [cancel], so the tag is not preventing other, more relevant from being placed on questions. I don't see how the tag is harming anything, and there are a lot of other actively harmful things going on that should be prioritized over burninating a merely useless tag.

Comment: Now, that is a reason to ignore the existence of the tag. The one you already gave in the answer is at best a head-scratcher.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm sure Robert was being sarcastic. He should know that even if it's not doing harm right now, in the future it could which will end in a most wasteful usage of everyones' effort.

Comment: Just to back up the `there are no questions with only [cancel]`, [here is a SEDE query to prove it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/232959/find-posts-where-x-is-the-only-tag?TargetTagName=cancel)